# Problema em gerar múltiplos gráficos

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho pouca experiencia com o R e estou apanhando um bocado para gerar um ggplot com 5 geom_lin. Poderiam me ajudar?

A base de dados são cinco séries anuais, em meses.

```
     2014    2015   2016    2017   2018
jan   10      8     7,5     5      9
Fev   11     12     8      2,35    4,1
Mar   7,5     9     2,5     1,7     3,57 
Abr   2,78    11,5  21      15      18
Mai   10      8     7,5     5      9
jun   11     12     8      2,35    4,1
jul   11     12     8      2,35    4,1
ago   7,5     9     2,5     1,7     3,57
Set   7,5     9     2,5     1,7     3,57 
out   2,78    11,5  21      15      18
nov   10      8     7,5     5      9
dez   11     12     8      2,35    4,1

data.frame(dados)
a= dados$2014
b= dados$2015
c= dados$2016
d= dados$2017
e= dados$2018
f= dados$meses

ggplot(data=dados, aes(meses())+
geom_line(aes(y=a), color="red")+
geom_line(aes(y=b), color="blue")+
geom_line(aes(y=c), color="green")+
geom_line(aes(y=d), color= "black")+
geom_line(aes(y=e), color="white")
```

Quando testo a rotina, mostra que esta faltando uma aes, quando corrijo fala para ajustar os parâmetros (x, y). Acredito que o R esteja considerando o número dos dados do eixo y, como eixo x, em alguma situação. O R ainda está desordenando os meses no eixo x, acredita que possa ser a falha para plotar o grafico???

Valeu!

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro reestruturei seus dados para o formato `long` (colunas com os meses, anos e os valores) utilizando a função `gather` do pacote `tidyr`:

```
library(tidyr)
dados_long <- gather(dados, ano, valor, X2014:X2018)
```

O problema dos meses em ordem alfabética, eu contornei forçando os níveis do fator "respeitarem" a ordem que aparece na coluna `meses`. Para a criação de um gráfico para cada ano, os agrupei dentro do `aes` com a opção `group` e os diferenciei com cores diferentes: `colour = ano`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = dados_long, aes(x = factor(meses, level = dados$meses), y = valor, group = ano, colour = ano)) + 
  geom_line() +
  xlab("Meses")
```

`dput` dos dados:

```
structure(list(meses = c("jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "jun", 
"jul", "ago", "Set", "out", "nov", "dez"), X2014 = c(10, 11, 
7.5, 2.78, 10, 11, 11, 7.5, 7.5, 2.78, 10, 11), X2015 = c(8, 
12, 9, 11.5, 8, 12, 12, 9, 9, 11.5, 8, 12), X2016 = c(7.5, 8, 
2.5, 21, 7.5, 8, 8, 2.5, 2.5, 21, 7.5, 8), X2017 = c(5, 2.35, 
1.7, 15, 5, 2.35, 2.35, 1.7, 1.7, 15, 5, 2.35), X2018 = c(9, 
4.1, 3.57, 18, 9, 4.1, 4.1, 3.57, 3.57, 18, 9, 4.1)), .Names = c("meses", 
"X2014", "X2015", "X2016", "X2017", "X2018"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa transformar seus dados de "wide" para "long" format. Eu uso a função `melt` do pacote `data.table`:

```
# criando os dados 
set.seed(1)
yrs <- c(2014:2018)

df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(yrs, function(x) {
  out <- data.frame(runif(12, 0, 12))
  names(out) <- x
  out
}))

df <- do.call(cbind, list(data.frame(meses = factor(month.name, levels = month.name)), df))

# carregue o pacote ggplot2
library(ggplot2)
dados <- data.table::melt(df, "meses") # transforme de wide para long

ggplot(dados, aes(meses, value)) + 
 geom_line(aes(group = variable, color = variable)) + # precisa agroupar a variavel
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.75))
```

Gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]